# Google Maps 'Place Autocomplete' Not Finding Addresses with Apartment & Number Range

Tags: autocomplete, range, street-address

Google's 'Place Autocomplete' doesn't show any results for an address with an apartment number and street number range e.g. "2/61-69 Macquarie St, Sydney NSW 2000" (apartment 2, of the building located at 61-69 Macquarie Street).

However, it does show results for "61-69 Macquarie St, Sydney NSW 2000" and "2/69 Macquarie St, Sydney NSW 2000".

Is there a way to get it to find the full address - or maybe some javascript could trim the "2/61-" off before google searches for it, or get Google to ignore that part of the typed string when it looks up possible addresses and add it back to the matching results.